# How do I change the depth when using addChild?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm adding a bg to the same canvas, but it's overlapping everything added before it.

I want to change the depth and make it appear beneath everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

addChildAt(childObject, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Also there is setChildIndex(child:DisplayObject, index:int):void, but you should manage your depths either by addChildAt or create your children in the right order i.e. bg first.